# Bridging Header File can't find an imported Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, ios-library

I'm trying to import [this library](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder) (SCRecorder) into my Swift project using the "Bridging Header File" method. But I really can't make it work. When I try to build the project, I get the following error :

```
error: 'SCRecorder/SCRecorder.h' file not found 
#import <SCRecorder/SCRecorder.h>
```

Here is the content of my bridging header file :

```
#ifndef Project_Bridging_Header_h
#define Project_Bridging_Header_h

#import <SCRecorder/SCRecorder.h>

#endif
```

And here is my project structure :

[image]

Of course I have added the reference to the Bridging Header File in my Build Settings. I'm almost sure it's just a path issue... But after some hours spent on this, I really can't find a solution.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : Instead of importing the project directly, I have added it with the CocoaPods method, and I get a new error :

```
library not found for -lSCRecorder
```

Comment: Is the SCRecorder project setup to export it's header file to that location?  If not then it will not be found.

Comment: @Putz1103 To be honest, I don't really know. How can I check that ?

Comment: Your framework (according to your import statement) should be named `SCRecorder.Framework`, not `SCRecorderFramework`

Comment: @l'L'l So should I edit something ?

Comment: Maybe try renaming the directory `SCRecorderFramework` (assuming it's the framework) as mentioned.

Comment: @l'L'l Instead, I have completely removed it and have tried to import it with the CocoaPods method. Now, I get the following error : library not found for -lSCRecorder

Comment: That's a different problem and not the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I figured it out. I just didn't use the *.xcworkspace project after installing pods... After opening my project with this file, everything works well, as expected.

Thanks for your help, especially @kaizoku for suggesting me to use this file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the library using 'cocoapods' 
There could be something wrong while importing the project manually.

[Here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) is a tutorial on how to install Cocospods and initialise your podfile in your application.

Then you can add `pod 'SCRecorder'` in the Podfile and go back to the terminal and type `pod install`.
This will install all the dependent libraries for SCRecorder.

Finally, go and try running the build. It should work.

 Safe side, keep a backup of this build.
Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have done that now, but I get a new error : "library not found for -lPods".

Comment: You need to open yourproject.xcworkspace 
I hope thats what you're doing. The xcodeproj file will give you errors

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with pods. Basically trying to run my UI tests, Xcode complained about missing pods. Solution to this was:

1. go to project file (main not a target)
2. click on the "Info" tab (most left)
3. set proper pod configuration for UI tests target ("Configurations" section right under "Deployment Target")

Working!

A bit more about this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2695